# How do I opt for First Year choice method?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, h-1b-visa

I received my H1B on October 1, 2017 and my wife is on H4 visa.

As I wanted to opt for the First Yr choice method, I filed for an extension in April, 2018 as I was unable to satisfy the Substantial Presence test. Now, I have satisfied the SBT.

What is the procedure for opting for the First Year choice method and filing taxes as Resident alien (married filing jointly)?

Comment: @PeteB. It's about income tax for immigrants.

Comment: Generic recommendation: start with [pub 519](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-519)